# input hidden value limit in html

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to put an entire 20kb jpg file content in input hidden value, but when I receive the data I only get 4kb file. What is the problem ?

I am using the following code to read jpg from a server and upload to another server.

```
<?php
$filename = "filetocopy.jpg";
$filedata = file_get_contents($filename);
file_put_contents("filetocopy1.jpg", $filedata);
echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\"><html><head><title></title>";

echo "<script LANGUAGE = "."Javascript"." type"."test/javascript".">";

echo  "function doSubmit() {";
    //alert('function called.');
echo    "document.forms[\"postjsform\"].submit();";
echo "}";

echo "</script>";

echo "</head>";

echo "<body onload='doSubmit();'>";

echo "<!-- Start of FORM -->";
echo "<form id=\"postjsform\" action=\"postjs2.php\" method=\"POST\">";
echo "Hidden Data: <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hiddendata\" value=" . $filedata . ">";
echo "<br>";
echo "</form>";
echo "<!-- End of FORM -->";

echo "</body></html>";

?>
```

Comment: Did you URL encode that file content? Did you try to put it in a textarea, or chunk it in several hidden fields?

Comment: Please show more code. Is this a normal form upload?

Comment: What server-side technology are you using? The problem could be due to a maximum request length setting on the server.

Comment: i guess server side limit is an issue. how can i handle that ?

Comment: look at post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in your php.ini file.

Comment: as the size of data is not fixed, can I do some split mechanism ? like find out the server permitted length and send data in that much splits ? is there a way i can use ajax and send it ?

Comment: post_max_size = 8M for me ..... does that mean i can transfer 8mbs of data ? in that case i should be easily transfer 20k data as I am doing now ! and upload_max_filesize = 2M

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any HTML for the form, I imagine the problem is there.

For example, you could be using `method="get"` instead of `method="post"` and be running into an URL length limitation.

Two things I am certain of here: Something is truncating your data, and it's not your PHP.